# Trouble with threads in OSX and Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, multithreading, macos, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

Running the following code in IRB:

```
t = Thread.new { loop { puts 'Hi' } }
```

I receive a single *hi* and then no more output.  Only if I begin pressing the enter key do I receive output as expected until I discontinue pressing enter.

If I do *t.join*, everything acts as expected

The problem happens in IRB, pry and ripl using ruby 1.9.2-p180 and 1.9.2-p290 under rvm 1.8.0 in OSX 10.7 and rvm 1.6.20 in OSX 10.6

readline is installed via *rvm pkg install readline*

Thank you for any insight

Comment: Is the question about the code, or the code *as it runs in IRB*? IRB does wacky things under the hood, so those are very different questions.

Comment: As it runs in IRB and ripl.  I know IRB is wacky but that doesn't mean that the problem is either caused by IRB/ripl or insurmountable if it is.

Comment: When I run the code from a `.rb` file it acts as I'd expect closing without a single 'hi'. Then I tried the following code both from a file and irb `Thread.new{ loop{ puts 'Hi'; sleep 2} }`. It seems irb leaves the Thread running anyway.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I'm seeing. When I run that code in IRB, it sleeps until I hold down the enter key.

Comment: Weird, for me on irb that last piece of code it keeps printing 'Hi' every 2 seconds. I guess it really has to do with irb more than the code then.

Comment: Well, it's also happening for me with pry and ripl aside from IRB.  I think it's something about how Ruby is configured in my environment.  It's happening for me in both OSX 10.6 and 10.7.  Can you describe your OS/Ruby environment?

Comment: I'm currently on Windows7 ruby1.9.2p180. The other question you found that was almost identical to this also was running osx so I was investigating if there was some info on it but cannot find anything useful. It'd be a shame if this question remains un-answered as well.

Comment: Thanks, yep it's working fine for me in Windows and Linux as well.  Pretty sure it's something with the Ruby implementation is OSX.  Thank you very much for your help though

Comment: Please list as an answer and mark it answered after 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of *readline* on OSX are blocking.  If you experience the behavior above, you can disable readline by putting

```
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = false
```

in .irbrc